# Windows 10 - Installing Django

Tags: python, django, pip

Getting the attached error when am trying to install Django.

throws up the following error
"could not find the version that satisfies the requirement install"

[image: Command screen shot]

Comment: Install pip with `python get-pip.py`, then install django(`pip install django`).

Comment: Did that. getting the same error

Comment: Instead of posting a hard to read screenshot.. *post the actual text* as well as what you have tried/researched

Comment: Show what you have done .

Comment: Copy pasting the text from command prompt
C:\Users\viku.jain>python c:\python27\get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\viku.jain>install django
'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\viku.jain>python c:\python27\get-pip.py install django
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install

Answer (score 0):

```
cd c:\Users\viku.jain\Downloads
python get-pip.py
pip install django==1.9
```

or you can install django using Git

Make sure that you have [Git](http://git-scm.com/) installed and that you can run its commands from a shell

```
git clone git://github.com/django/django.git
pip install -e django/
```

the you can start your work by **django-admin** utility command